# embed google map on website that showing real-time position

Tags: php, javascript, dictionary

I am writing a map-based iphone app that will send the current location data to the web server in real-time manner
The web server then generate, also real-time, a page with google map embedded that show the real-time locations of the devices that are connected to the server, WITHOUT refreshing the web page.
But this is just my design!
Can google map API assist me in this function? Or any idea/suggestions?
I intend to use php and javascript to do the server and client side programming.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Marker - Google Maps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319756/add-marker-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: what do you mean by "without refreshing"? Since new data is generated i see no other way but to update your by using Ajax.

Comment: @PauloBueno
that means the markers on the map that was embedded on the page will dynamically change position.

Comment: the real-time concept is a bit like the instance chatting room website, which shows instantly the updated message.

Comment: ok, but the data must arrive your client page. See no other way but ajax or html5 sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question,
With Google Maps API V3 Javascript you can dynamically place Markers on the map.
Do you have an idea to get real-time location of devices ?

Comment: Yes! I got the location data using Core Location in iOS SDK!

Comment: You juste have to get every X (milli)seconds the location of devices connected with javascript and add markers on the map