# How can I from a desktop get a user mobile location. Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I start a small google map project. On this project I make a request from the database and display all the locations on the map but I will like to add a extra function on the map. I will like to have a function that I can see on the map the user mobile location.

The user accept
to give the current location on the mobile and from a desktop I can see where the user is and
it keeping tracking the mobile location.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use Google Latitude. It does just that. If you are going to code, use its API: https://developers.google.com/latitude/

Comment: @Renan But how can I display on my custom goolge map? Thanks

Comment: This discussion would quickly derail to an online tutorial, so I'd rather recommend you keep reading on the Maps API. Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701077/add-marker-function-with-google-maps-api