# jquery "this" is confusing here

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a code snippet that's working for my "maps" feature - following is the code:

```
var latlang = new google.maps.LatLng(myjsonobject[pos].geocode.latitude, myjsonobject[pos].geocode.longitude);

$('#map_canvas').gmap({
    'center': latlang, 
    'zoom': 10, 
    'disableDefaultUI':false, 
    'callback': function() {
        var self = this;                         
        self
            .addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() })
            .click(function() {
                self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': address }, this);
            });                         
    }
});
```

The variable `latlang` is provided with the latitude and longitude of a given location. Then, the `map_canvas` is the div where the Google map is displayed with the `latlang` as its inputs.
In the callback function, `self` is a variable assigned with `this`. This is the place where I am confused. What is `this` in this context? Can anyone throw some light on `getCenter()` and the `this` inside `self.openInfoWindow` please?

How is the whole code working and showing me the result?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628. Specifically this is in the context of an onclick handler so check out rule 4. But jQuery can change what `this` is as well so check out jQuery documentation.

Comment: thanks for your response... The code is being used in my HTML5 mobile app where a set of addresses are shown as result and when I click on an address, the map is shown for that address. All this is working only for first time (first address click).i.e. if I select a new address next, the map is still showing the old address and its position :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has function scope.
This actually means that inside each function `this` refers to a different thing.
If you want to access a certain scope in another function, a common approach is to store the desired context (`this`) in another variable (such as `self` because it's naming is suggestive of it's value).
Here's a simple demo that might clear this:

```
function a() {
    this.someValue = 'some value';
    var self = this;

    function b() {
        alert(this.someValue); // it's undefined, because "this" 
                               // refers to function b's context

        alert(self.someValue); // this works as expected, because self 
                               // is a reference to a's context
    }

    // call b(), to actually test this
    b();
} 
a();
```

To simplify your code and make it more readable, let's separate the functions and name them. 
So your old code:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({
    'center': latlang, 
    'zoom': 10, 
    'disableDefaultUI':false, 
    'callback': function() {
        var self = this;                         
        self
            .addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() })
            .click(function() {
                self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': address }, this);
            });                         
    }
});
```

becomes:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({
    'center': latlang, 
    'zoom': 10, 
    'disableDefaultUI':false, 
    'callback': callback
});

function callback() {
    var self = this;  

    this
        .addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() })
        .click(onClick);    
}

function onClick() {
    // self is callback's context
    // which actually points to the map instance

    // this points to the context of the click function, 
    // which actually is the dom element that was clicked on, 
    // which is the marker
    self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': address }, this);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response... The code is being used in my HTML5 mobile app where a set of addresses are shown as result and when I click on an address, the map is shown for that address. All this is working only for first time (first address click).i.e. if I select a new address next, the map is still showing the old address and its position :(

Comment: in my code, when I alert "self" it says [object, object]. The "latlang" is being updated fine (with any new address' lat, lang coordinates) but that's not reflecting in the "addmarker"... 
It always shows my first address! :(

Comment: Please see the full (updated) answer. Maybe it will help you understand the issue better :)

Comment: Sure. this should really help. I was going through a similar post here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701077/add-marker-function-with-google-maps-api

Answer (score 2):

'this' is context to `$('#map_canvas')`

The whole DOM tree of map_canvas is stored into 'this' variable

Comment: thanks for your response... 
All this is working fine only for the first time. The code is being used in my HTML5 mobile app where a set of addresses are shown as result and when I click on an address, the map is shown for that address.
All this is working only for first time (first address click).i.e. if I select a new address next, the map is still showing the old address and its position :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': latlang, 'zoom': 10, 'disableDefaultUI':false, 
'callback': function(   event   ) {
           var self = this;     
...
```

as you capture the event in that function this will (always?!) be equivalent to

```
$(event.currentTarget)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

'this' is a jQuery object when you are inside your own jQuery functions.