# Why itsn't displaying marker on map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've tried diferent codes and still don't know why my marker itsn't displaying. 
I've been searching and reading the google developers documentation and tried all the ways that they explain and nothing. Have also try to see if there is any sintax error (and it has to be...) but as I'm newbie for me it looks like there is no mistake.

So, someone knows what is wrong in my code?

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<div id="map"></div><!-- #map-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAp9iQ2oC3PEvy20_6aDpAPGLT8sFDqAjI&libraries=geometry,places&signed_in=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', gmaps_results_initialize );

    function gmaps_results_initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), {
        zoom:           3,
        center:         new google.maps.LatLng( 28.291564, 16.62913 ),
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
       },
       zoomControl: true,
       zoomControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
       },
       scaleControl: true,
       streetViewControl: true,
       streetViewControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
       },
       fullscreenControl: true
       });
       var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

       // Try HTML5 geolocation.
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
             var pos = {
             lat: position.coords.latitude,
             lng: position.coords.longitude
             };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            map.setCenter(pos);
            }, function() {
               handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
         } else {
           // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
           handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
           }

        };      
</script>
<script>
       var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
       var mapOptions = {}
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({});

      // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
       marker.setMap(map);
    </script>
<script src="/geo.js"></script>
<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because you are creating two objects for the map.
make map object a constant. Do not reinitialise it.

You have added the  marker  outside the function and that causes it to execute before the initialize method which will be called when google maps script loads and thus the marker is not added because map is not initialized . Create separate method TestMarker and call it from initialize.

```
function addMarker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
}

 function TestMarker() {
       CentralPark = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157);
       addMarker(CentralPark);
}
```

call TestMarker inside initialise function

Note : map is a constant here.

Comment: You mean like this? `const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ),` It's still not working. Anyway thank you for answering me.

Comment: Hi, thank you again. I called TestMarker function inside initialize and changed the second script code for the last one that you wrote. But, still not working. I have the feelling I'm a bit retarder...

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701077/add-marker-function-with-google-maps-api

Comment: Oh, I didn't find this question in Stack. Anyway, still not working. I believe I'm puttin the function call in the wrong place. Now it's even not showing the map... https://hooct.com/google-maps-api/

Comment: Have tried all the options from the stack overflow link that you send me and still not working. Have put TestMarker call in all possible places and still not working too. And people tells Javascript it's easy, hahahaha.