# How to mark latitude and longitude on Google Maps using vue js by json data obtained by ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-resource

This is my vue js script to get the json data using ajax request

```
    <script>
    new Vue({
  el: '#feed' ,
  data: {
    details: [],
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      var self = this;
      var id = window.location.href.split('=').pop()
             console.log(id)
      $.ajax({
            url: "https://",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (e) {
                if (e.status == 1) {
                    self.details = e.data;
                    console.log(e.data)
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('Error occurred');}
            }, error: function(){
            console.log('Error occurred');
            }
        });
    })
  },
})    </script>



 <script>
export default {
  name: 'google-map',
  props: ['name'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      mapName: this.name + "-map",
      markerCoordinates: [{
        latitude: 51.501527,
        longitude: -0.1921837
      }],
      map: null,
      bounds: null,
      markers: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    const element = document.getElementById(this.mapName)
    const mapCentre = this.markerCoordinates[0]
    const options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.latitude, mapCentre.longitude)
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
    this.markerCoordinates.forEach((coord) => {
      const position = new google.maps.LatLng(coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position,
        map: this.map
      });
    this.markers.push(marker)
      this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds.extend(position))
    });
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.google-map {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gray;
}
</style>
```

I am get errors as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export..
I am not getting any idea how to solve the same issue. Please help me to solve

This is my html code to display all the JSON data

```
<div class="m-single-article" id="feed">
<p>{{details.bussinessName}}</p> 
<p>{{details.pid}}</p>
<p v-for="inv in details.inventory">{{inv}}</p>
<p v-for="sub in details.sub_category">{{sub}}</p>
<div class="google-map" :id="mapName"></div>
</div>
```

But I am getting errors. Can anyone please help me to solve my issue. How can I able to get the lat and long to be displayed on the google maps. I am a beginner in vue js. Please help me to solve this issue.

Is there any another method to solve the same using google maps api? Please help me to have a solution
My js fiddle link without adding google maps is https://jsfiddle.net/kzc26bgs/1/

Comment: `mounted() {`? Use `mounted: function() {` instead

Comment: shuksin.ivan, that is valid javascript. @coder, are you using single file components and/or a module bundler?

Comment: alert the lat and lan coming or not tell me i will

Comment: Wow. The vuejs doc doesn't contain that new syntax.

Comment: @EricGuan I am using the same way as mentioned above? https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get/5 this url provides me with the values. I am able to display all other values expect google maps. Is there any way to load maps

Comment: The problem is with your `export`. If you're not using a module bundler like webpack or browserify, then your code will never work. It has nothing to do with ajax or vue or google maps.

Comment: is your requirement to place a marker on the google maps using the lat and lon obtained from the json data? @coder

Comment: @Wanderer yes.. It is what need to be done? What can I do

Comment: @EricGuan So, can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 sir, I didn't get you

Comment: @shukshin.ivan I tried but still the same error occured

Comment: hello u r getting the console.log(e.data) dude

Comment: yes sir, I am getting.. that json value is been displayed above..

Comment: can u alert the lan and lan r u getting use init map

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 i am getting lat and long from json data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701077/add-marker-function-with-google-maps-api

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kzc26bgs/1/

Comment: this much is fine for me @jeevanswamy21

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 How to make it is vue js code?

Comment: var options = {
               zoom: 6,
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.92, 77.25), // Centered
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
               mapTypeControl: false
           };

            // Init map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), options);

Comment: Sir, Its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158471/discussion-between-jeevanswamy21-and-coder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function initMap() {
var c = [{"status": true, "data": {"pid": 5, "bussinessName": "Xavier Tailoring shop", "services": "All kind of stitching works", "inventory": [], "workHr": "Monday :9:00AM to 20:0PM,Thuesday :9:00AM to 20:0PM,Wednesday :9:00AM to 20:0PM,Tuesday : 9:00AM to 20:0PM,Friday :9:00AM to 20:0PM,Saturday :9:00AM to 20:0PM,Sunday :9:00AM to 20:0PM", "description": "All kind of stitching works", "category": 11, "sub_category": ["Veg Hotel"], "lat": 9.52436859, "lon": 76.82810117, "contactName": "xavier", "contactEmail": "harisxavier@gmail.com", "contactOfficeAddress": "koovapally perubara road", "contactNumber": "8592808201", "contactOfficeNumber": "8592808201", "state": "Kerala", "city": "Koovappally", "place": "Kanjirapally - Erumely Road", "pincode": 686518, "referer": 24, "link": 31, "views": 0, "package": 1, "listing_pic": "default", "website": "example.com"}}];
  var myLatLng = {lat:c[0].data.lat  , lng:c[0].data.lon  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapName'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="mapName" style="width:267px; height: 270px" />
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AddKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

```
var options = {
                    zoom: 6,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.92, 77.25), // Centered
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false
                };

              // Init map
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), options);

 $.post("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getorderlist.htm", {
                    aa : aa,
                    output : output,

                }, function(data) {             

                }).done(function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);


                        //console.log( json);

                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) 
                    {   

                         var    
                  png='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';

                             // Init markers
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].lat , json[i].lon),
                                map: map,
                                title: 'Click Me ' + i,
                                icon:png
                            });

                            // Process multiple info windows
                            (function(marker, i) {
                                // add click event
                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                        content: json[k][i].address
                                    });
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                });
                            })(marker, i);                              

                        }                           


                }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }).complete(function() {
                    $("#btn-save").prop("disabled", false);

                });
```

Comment: how can it be? I am not getting

Comment: u can use u r ajax post insted of my ajax post change url and pass the data get the sucess function data to for loop it will automatically place marker

Comment: inside the mounted function?

Comment: on dom load use mounted function ,on ajax call use this map function k

Comment: sorry, still no getting

Comment: pass e.data.lat and lon to this json[i].lat

Comment: checked that too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example

Comment: Sir, thanks for the help I tried your fiddle code. Now the map has been loaded fine.. but error occurred with vue js

Comment: you can view only after add the key=AddKEY here you can see otherwise see this example iused this one https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158477/discussion-between-jeevanswamy21-and-coder).